# Crystal Reports dynamic parameters values

Tags: crystal-reports

I have crystal report with dynamic parameter (for example, linked on table COUNTRIES in some datebase).
How can i programmatically get allowed values for this parameter (list of countries)?
For static i can get default values using :

```
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(reporthPath);
        rd.ParameterFields; // contains params with default values collections
```

Dynamic parameters has no items in DefaultValues collection. I can retrieve existing connections for report, but where i can get relation between connection and dynamic parameters?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do that in Crystal Reports. It's better to *not* use dynamic parameter field; they make your report unnecessary slow. Instead convert them to a static parameter an fill the default values from your code; that's much faster plus you know what the accepted values are.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is incorrect - as of Crystal Reports XI (at least that's where my information comes from) it is possible; see
http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crsdk_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crtsktutorialsrdparametersdiscrete.htm, particularly parts 2(Creating a Report with Parameters) and 5(Create a ListBox Control that Displays Default Parameters)

basically the list of possible values can be taken from the default values list,

thanks,

MD-Tech

Comment: Yes I know that. Point is that this only works for default values entered manually *static* parameter fields. It doesn't work for *dynamic* parameter fields where the default values are filled from a chosen database table in the report. So unless you can prove this with a working code example I keep disagreeing with you.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the existing answers a little bit after running this problem to ground myself:

A `ParameterField` with a Static list of values has these values as items in its `DefaultValues` collection. The problem is that a `ParameterField` with a Dynamic list does not have these values pre-populated and the API does not seem to have a mechanism to query them.

A workaround involves using a Static list instead of a Dynamic one, but there may be hundreds of acceptable values which may change over time. Unless remembering to change the report(s) is appealing, a Dynamic list makes sense in this context.

In addition, using the `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ParameterField` reveals a property `BrowseField`. `BrowseField` has properties `TableAlias` and `Name` which you can query with ADO.NET. However, `BrowseField` is only populated for Static parameters; it is null when using a Dynamic parameter. This is currently documented as a "needs fixed" on SAP's knowledge base, [Article 2114469](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/0002114469).

So, once you somehow get the table and column name, use ADO.NET to query the database and stick those values into the `DefaultValues` collection of the Dynamic parameter. Consider using a naming convention for the parameters to make this easier. Perhaps use a static parameter that isn't used in the report to house your table and column information.